# Google Cloud Vision API Error: Unknown: None Stream removed

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, raspberry-pi, google-cloud-vision

I wrote a program for animal detection using Cloud Vision API to detect an object of a captured image from Raspberry Pi camera. If there is an animal to interrupt a process of sending email and SMS with the image. My Python script works just fine but sometimes randomly I get a strange error like this:

```
Unknown: None Stream removed.
```

How I fix this error and make my program more stable?

My code:

```py
def detectImage(self, image_name):
    path = '/home/pi/project/pictures/' + image_name
    max_results=1
    with open(path, 'rb') as image_file:
        content = image_file.read()
    image = vision.types.Image(content=content)
    objects = client.object_localization(image=image, max_results=max_results).localized_object_annotations
    image_file.close()
    for object_ in objects:
        if (object_.name == 'Animal' or object_.name == 'Cat' or object_.name == 'Dog' or object_.name == 'Bird' or object_.name == 'Insect'):
            print ('False Alarm: This is an animal!')
            if os.path.exists('/home/pi/project/pictures/' + image_name):
                os.remove('/home/pi/project/pictures/'+image_name) #Deletes the taken picture in case of False Alarm
                print 'File', image_name, 'has beeen deleted'
        else:
            Process(target=interact().takePicture(image_name)).start()
            print('Not an animal!')
```

The error:

```
Process Process-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)

  File "startup.py", line 70, in pir
    Process(target=interact().detectImage(image_name)).start()   #Start the procedure for animal detection.

  File "/home/pi/project/functions.py", line 305, in detectImage
    objects = client.object_localization(image=image, max_results=max_results).localized_object_annotations

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/cloud/vision_helpers/decorators.py", line 101, in inner
    response = self.annotate_image(request, retry=retry, timeout=timeout)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/cloud/vision_helpers/__init__.py", line 72, in annotate_image
    r = self.batch_annotate_images([request], retry=retry, timeout=timeout)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/cloud/vision_v1/gapic/image_annotator_client.py", line 234, in batch_annotate_images
    request, retry=retry, timeout=timeout, metadata=metadata

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/api_core/gapic_v1/method.py", line 143, in __call__
    return wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 59, in error_remapped_callable
    six.raise_from(exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc), exc)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/six.py", line 737, in raise_from
    raise value
Unknown: None Stream removed
```

Comment: Can you tell us what versions of your dependencies you're using? [Specifically this looks like an issue with an old version of `google-cloud-pubsub`.](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/4989)

Comment: Python 2.7.13
i don't know how i find the version of Google Cloud Vision. Also I didn't install the google-cloud-pubsub like the guy in the link that you have send me.

Comment: Can you include the output of `pip freeze`?

Comment: These don't look like you have `google-cloud-vision` or `google-cloud-pubsub` installed at all. FYI, you can edit your original question to add more details instead of putting them in comments like that.

Comment: Ok thanks , that's strange because i have installed the cloud vision and it's working following this tutorial: https://www.dexterindustries.com/howto/use-google-cloud-vision-on-the-raspberry-pi/

Comment: How are you running your script?

Comment: Raspberry Pi's Terminal

Comment: Specifically what command are you using?

Comment: python scriptname.py

Comment: And i need to use the credential command to be able to run the script with cloud vision like this: 

export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/home/pi/vision-000000.json
for every time go to the directory of the script from terminal , is there anyway to avoid to do that every time ?